# Yearly bar chart with quarterly data in the last column only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I aim to create a plot similar to the image where the '2020 Q4' data is in the same column as '2020'.
[image]

So far I was only able to place the 2020 Q4 data simply as an extra column.

The data is provided as a DataFrame like in the code below:

```
# DataFrame using arrays.
import pandas as pd
 
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'A':[10, 15, 20, 26, 27, 35, 15],
        'B':[20, 25, 32, 33, 50, 52, 8],
        'C':[30, 35, 41, 49, 52, 53, 25]}
 
# Creates pandas DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index =['2015',
                                '2016',
                                '2017',
                                '2018',
                                '2019',
                                '2020',
                                '2020 Q4',])
# plotting the data
df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the plot order of the last bar be `A A-Q4 B B-Q4 C C-Q4` insted of `A B C A-Q4 B-Q4 C-Q4` or is the sum of subcategories `A A-Q4` etc. not important for comparisons?

Comment: To be fair it would be nicer to have A A-Q4 B B-Q4 etc. However having it on the column rather than next as a separate column is the more important requirement ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems have to be addressed here. First, one has to transpose the Q4 data into the row above. Second, the corresponding columns `A A-Q4` etc. need similar colors to make it clear that they belong to the same category. [Matplotlib's tab20 colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html) comes in handy. Here is one approach:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# DataFrame using arrays.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'A':[10, 15, 20, 26, 27, 35, 15],
        'B':[20, 25, 32, 33, 50, 52, 8],
        'C':[30, 35, 41, 49, 52, 53, 25]}
 
# Creates pandas DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index =['2015',
                                '2016',
                                '2017',
                                '2018',
                                '2019',
                                '2020',
                                '2020 Q4',])
#get column names
columns = df.columns
#store data of last row and create a new dataframe without the last row
val_q4 = df.iloc[-1].values
df1 = df.iloc[:-1]
#alternatively, one can simply overwrite df it doesn't matter to remove the Q4 row
#df = df.iloc[:-1]

#generate additional columns for Q4 data
new_columns = [f(item) for item in columns for f in (lambda x: x, lambda x: x+" Q4")]
df1 = df1.reindex(columns=new_columns)
#store Q4 data in last row
df1.iloc[-1, range(1, 2*len(columns), 2)] = val_q4

#create corresponding color pairs using the tab20 colormap
colors = plt.cm.tab20(np.linspace(0, 1, 20))
df1.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True, color=colors)
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Restrictions: It relies on your data structure that the rows are already sorted and the last two rows are "Year" and "Year Q4". Tab20 limits the use to 10 columns `A, B, C,...,J` because beginning with `K`, the colors will not be unique. However, stacked bar graphs with more than 10 categories should be outlawed anyhow.

Comment: This solution is very elegant and worked seamlessly! I especially appreciate that you don't have to manually input the column names and the colours  -  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce Q4 values for A, B and C rows and initialise it to zero for all years except 2020. This should give you the desired result.

For example, see this updated code:

```
# DataFrame using arrays.
import pandas as pd
 
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'A':[10, 15, 20, 26, 27, 35, 15],
        'B':[20, 25, 32, 33, 50, 52, 8],
        'C':[30, 35, 41, 49, 52, 53, 25]}

# additional data initialise with zero for all years
add_data = {'AQ4':[0]*5,
        'BQ4':[0]*5,
        'CQ4':[0]*5} 

# take the last element in list A, B, C and append it to add_data dict
add_data['AQ4'].append(data['A'].pop())
add_data['BQ4'].append(data['B'].pop())
add_data['CQ4'].append(data['C'].pop())

# concatenate the 2 dicts
data.update(add_data)

# Creates pandas DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index =['2015',
                                '2016',
                                '2017',
                                '2018',
                                '2019',
                                '2020'])
# plotting the data
df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

Note that I have removed 2020 Q4 index when creating the data frame.